# Symlink inside profile

Tags: users

I forked a repo from a third party development team that I am taking over for, and inside the "profiles" folder is a file just named foo.

When I open it, it as this ../../foo and nothing else.

Is this a symlink to the install profile?

There is an install profile, just not in the docroot folder, it sits outside of it with the grunt and build files.

If so, is there a difference on how Nginx and Apache handle symlinks?  They used a Nginx server to develop and I'm using Apache.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly common practice to use symlink on web server. You might also see it on your private folder so that I can be hosted on a NAS or AWS EFS for example.

Symlink should work regardless of the web server you use as they are specific to the server operating system and not to the web server by itself.

Comment: I get they are fairly common. I'm asking is that I mentioned a symlink file, and if it is. What should I look for to make sure my webserver is following it.